# I am trying to make a progam that records key presses and replays them back, but it seems to be pressing extra keys

Tags: python

When I test this by typing "hello" and call playStrokes() it presses "helloello", and I just want it to write hello. I've tried printing out i in playStrokes and everything seems normal.

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keys = Controller()


def playStrokes():
    for i in range(len(strokes)):
        keys.tap(strokes[i])


strokes = []


def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.shift:
        print(strokes)
        playStrokes()
        return False


    try:
        strokes.append(key)

    except AttributeError:
        print("ERROR")




with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as keyListener:
    keyListener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when **playStrokes()** is called the keyListener picks up the **keys.tap(strokes[i])** as well, this is because the keyListener will stop listening after **playStrokes()** is finished at return false...

just modify **on_press** to be

```
def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.shift:
        return False 
    try:
        strokes.append(key)
    except AttributeError:
        print("ERROR")
```

and call **playStrokes()** after the keyListener.join() stops

```
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as keyListener:
    keyListener.join()  
    playStrokes()
```